How to use client side encryption for Cloud SQL Postgres in a way that only the end user have access to their data?
I have an App running at GCP App Engine which stores data in a Cloud SQL PostgreSQL.
Since this App is aimed to be used by various different clients, I need a way to guarantee to them that they are the only ones that have access to their respective data, even when I am the one who manages the cloud services on GCP.
The only way I found that this could be achieved is by means of client side encryption (please correct me if I am wrong).
I couldn't find information about achieve this goal with keys been stored locally, only with keys been stored in Cloud KMS (Can this solve the problem?). Here it was just mentioned in the overview.

You could do this using ROW LEVEL SECURITY to restrict access to rows. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-rowsecurity.html To encrypt the data you can use the pgcrypto extension: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgcrypto.html

In my actual implementation, the data is stored to Cloud SQL Postgre SQL using a php connection with the database. Since all files are in cloud storage the implementation of all postgres security or cryptography would also be in the cloud storage. How can the end user know if I didn't change the reference implementation without notice?

Is there a way, using pgAdmin, to make the data be encrypted before send? My App runs in the browser

client-side encryption is done in the client.  So none of the tags you used for this question are appropriate.
